# Stable equivalence of generating sets of a finitely-generated group?

Tags: gr.group-theory, free-groups

This question came about when I was naively considering to what extent generating sets for finitely-generated groups are unique.

Let $G$ be a group and let $\phi_1, \phi_2 : F_k \to G$ be two surjective homomorphisms from a free group on $k$ letters $F_k$.  Given a natural number $K \geq k$ let the surjective homomorphisms $\Phi_1^K, \Phi_2^K : F_K \to G$ be the obtained by extending the corresponding maps $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ to send the $K-k$ other letters in $F_K$ to the identity.

Does there exist some $K$ such that $\Phi_1^K \circ \alpha = \Phi_2^K$ for some automorphism $\alpha$ of $F_K$?

Comment: This is not even true for $K=k$. There are automorphisms of one-relator groups not induced by free group automorphisms.

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda Thanks for your comment.  I'm sorry I don't  follow how that is relevant -- I am asking if given $k$ there exists some $K$.

Comment: I see, I misread the question. I am not quite sure what you mean by "trivially extending the corresponding maps $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$". Where do the new generators in $F_K$ get sent to in $G$?

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda The identity.  I'll edit for clarity -- thank you.

Comment: Do you have a non-trivial example of the statement you expect to be true in general? Eg an example when no $\alpha$ exists for $K=k$ but there is some for $K>k$?

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda Following Andy Putman's helpful tip, the wikipedia page for Nielsen equivalence gives an example with $k=2$ and $K=3$ (but $K=2$ does not work) for the Dihedral group of order 10.  In a footnote of that wikipedia page, it is stated that this is true of all minimal generating sets for finite groups.

Comment: At least for finitely presented groups, I think your question is about a strengthening of Tietze's theorem (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Tietze+transformation) which implies that any two presentations can be reached by a sequence of moves adding and removing generators and applying free group autmorphisms. Your question asks whether we can arrange to add all the generators first, then apply the automorphisms, then remove the remaining generators. So it might be a good idea to look carefully at the proof of Tietze's theorem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is $K=2k$, which is an exercise. Here is a sketch: Let $f\colon \langle x_i\rangle\to G$ be a surjective homomorphism, and $h\colon \langle x_i\rangle*\langle y\rangle\to G$ the map defined by $h(x_i)=f(x_i)$, $h(y)=e$. Let $g\in G$ be arbitrary, and choose $w\in\langle x_i\rangle$ such that $f(w)=g$. Let $\alpha$ be the automorphism of $\langle x_i\rangle*\langle y\rangle$ which maps $y$ to $yw$ and leaves the other generators alone. Then $h(\alpha(y))=g$. Do this $k$ times, one for each element of your second generating tuple, then reverse the process, swapping the roles of the $x$ and $y$.

$K=2k-1$ doesn't suffice, by Kapovich and Weidmann, who in "Nielsen equivalence in a class of random groups" construct small-cancellation examples.

Answer (score 7):

The keyword here is "Nielsen equivalence".  Two size-$n$ generating sets for a group $G$ are called Nielsen equivalent if the associated surjections $F_n \rightarrow G$ differ by an automorphism of $F_n$.  This is an interesting and fairly subtle condition, and it is definitely not completely understood.  For instance, there is a famous conjecture of Wiegold saying that if $G$ is a finite simple group, then for $n \geq 3$ any two $n$-element generating sets for $G$ are Nielsen equivalent.

Of course, you are interested in the "stable" version of this where you allow the addition of trivial generators.  One theme here is that for many classes of groups, there are many Nielsen equivalence classes of "minimal" generating sets, but only one for non-minimal generating sets (for instance, the ones you get by adding a trivial generator to a minimal generating set).

I hope that other people can give you precise references to the literature on this -- I used to have a decent bibliography of this in my notes from an old collaboration, but I can't find it right now -- but at the very least you can find a lot by searching mathscinet now that you know the right technical term.

(This started off life as a comment, but grew a little too long.  Hopefully other people can point you to some papers on this)

Comment: To add to this: my initial comment is just stating the fact there are one-relator groups defined by $\langle A \mid w = 1 \rangle$ resp. $\langle A \mid w' = 1 \rangle$ such that the two groups are isomorphic, but that $w$ and $w'$ are not Nielsen equivalent (here the work by Zieschang, Pietrowski, and Pride, among others, is important; see II.2 in Lyndon-Schupp). One key-word is "$T$-systems", at least for Pride's papers.